# How to display empty message like "No Data Found" when using AG Grid Server Side Row Model

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

title says it all.

I have been using AG Grid with Server Side Row Model.

I have go through their documentation but I was not able to find a way to handle empty data.

Anyone have came across this problem and how to did you implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using server-side row model you can utilize two [overlays](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-overlays) that AG Grid supplies. The first is the loading overlay, and the second, the one I think you want, is no rows overlay.

For example in the datasource before calling `params.success()` or `params.fail()` you can check if your row data is empty and hide/show the overlay like in the following example:

```
rowData.length ? params.api.hideOverlay() : params.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
```

It is also possible to supply a custom [overlay component](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-overlay/#simple-no-rows-overlay-component)

Comment: If you give an example as I did, users can understand your point better.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy.

We can use overlayNoRowsTemplate for this purpose (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays/#custom-overlays)

We set it like that in our grid options

```
overlayNoRowsTemplate:
  '<span style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow; color: red;">No Data Available</span>',
```

Then we check data count and call the showNoRowsOverlay method if no data is available.

```
function onBtShowNoRows() {
  gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
}

function createServerSideDatasource(server) {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
      console.log('params', params);
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);

      var response = server.getData(params.request);

      if (response.rows.length === 0) {
        onBtShowNoRows();
      }

      setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.success) {
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rows,
            rowCount: response.lastRow,
          });
        } else {
          params.fail();
        }
      }, 500);
    },
  };
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Here's my example: https://plnkr.co/edit/L85rC8Y3kKW3OMRj?preview